Disable encryption on wireguard
Im interested in the tunneling capabilities of a VPN but I don't want any overhead or extra added latency (for running certain applications over the tunnel). Also, my apps already encrypt traffic over TLS.
It's possible to disable encryption on OpenVPN (for example) but I can't find a way to do it in Wireguard. Is it possible?

Perhaps GRE is better suited for the task?

Wireguard doesn't support plaintext tunnelling, its not meant to.
I think using a pubilc facing tunnel without securing the packets is not a sound idea.
I'd be very surprised if your latency requirements really are a problem, I imagine the encryption cant be adding more than 50 microseconds at worse per packet.
You can use an ipip tunnel. See ip link add type ipip help for more info and the man page explains the parameters. This would be the 'unencrypted' version.
Wireguard is effectively built on top of these tunnel types so this would take out the encryption.
I've never done this (because its silly) so I cant offer a great deal of suggestion on how to set one up, but this should at least point you in the right kind of direction.
To me it sounds as if you've got an idea of getting traffic from one endpoint to another endpoint. My obvious question to you would be why dont you just host whatever you're doing on a normal external TCP port and use a firewall to protect both ends of the connection in terms of access control?
